# Remove <u> tag from table Cell dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

In my HTML I have placed the following code for a cell

```
cell.innerHTML = "<u>View All</u>";
```

Inside my onclick event for the cell I have following code(example, its based on some condition where I frame the below, not actual data)

```
cell.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>xyz</td><td>abc</td></tr></table>";
```

The problem I am facing is that after onclick, xyz and abc are underlined eventhogh I changed the innnerHTML same way I did before. How can I get rid of underline part on onClick event?

PS: I am relatively new to HTML.

Thanks In advance guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give <**u**> tag an id (for eg. #element-id), then use the following code snippet.

```
var element = document.getElementById("element-id");
element.outerHTML = "";
delete element;
```

Comment: outerelement was something new for me. I tried below and it worked:                cell.outerHTML = "<table><tr><td>xyz</td><td>abc</td></tr></table>";        Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem bro.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `cell` is not within a `<u>` element itself. If it is, then the underline is being applied to the entire of `cell` regardless of the `<u>` tag inside it.

Comment: No its not, as I mentioned the <u>  part is added by code as shown above